# Conda build fails with "TypeError: create_function()" error

Tags: python, conda, conda-build

I am running `conda build` using a recipe that downloads the tar.gz file from PyPi.

This fails with the following error message:

> ```
> TypeError: create_function() got an unexpected keyword argument 'narg'
> ```

I have simplified the recipe file and reproduced the error. The contents are as follows:

```yaml
package:
  name: binda
  version: 1.0.9

source:
  url: https://pypi.io/packages/source/b/binda/binda-1.0.9.tar.gz
  sha256: 86c1eef6c48ee520f244aac2ebcc8cd62f2e0c0ec97d88b9c1a5ea8719c40e82

requirements:
  host:
    - python >=3.6
    - hatchling
    - hatch-vcs
    - pip
  run:
    - python >=3.6
    - pandas
    - numpy
```

I have checked the link to the package and confirmed the checksum.

I have also tried recreating the environments, testing on standard Python, Miniforge and Anaconda environments. All three fail with the same error.

The full error message with environment settings and stack trace are included below:

---

> ```
> (binda) C:\Users\jlcas\PythonProjects\binda>conda build binda 
> WARNING: No numpy version specified in conda_build_config.yaml. 
> Falling back to default numpy value of 1.22 Adding in variants from
> internal_defaults Attempting to finalize metadata for binda
>
> # >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
>
>     Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "C:\ProgramData\mambaforge-pypy3\lib\site-packages\conda_index\index\convert_cache.py",
> line 158, in remove_prefix
>         conn.create_function("migrate_basename", narg=1, func=basename, deterministic=True)
>       File "C:\ProgramData\mambaforge-pypy3\Lib\_sqlite3.py", line 324, in wrapper
>         return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
>       File "C:\ProgramData\mambaforge-pypy3\Lib\_sqlite3.py", line 305, in wrapper
>         return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
>     TypeError: create_function() got an unexpected keyword argument 'narg'
>
>     During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
>     Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "C:\ProgramData\mambaforge-pypy3\lib\site-packages\conda\exception_handler.py",
> line 17, in __call__
>         return func(*args, **kwargs)
>       File "C:\ProgramData\mambaforge-pypy3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py",
> line 64, in main_subshell
>         exit_code = do_call(args, parser)
>       File "C:\ProgramData\mambaforge-pypy3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\conda_argparse.py",
> line 143, in do_call
>         result = plugin_subcommand.action(getattr(args, "_args", args))
>       File "C:\ProgramData\mambaforge-pypy3\lib\site-packages\conda_build\plugin.py",
> line 10, in build
>         execute(*args, **kwargs)
>       File "C:\ProgramData\mambaforge-pypy3\lib\site-packages\conda_build\cli\main_build.py",
> line 568, in execute
>         outputs = api.build(
>       File "C:\ProgramData\mambaforge-pypy3\lib\site-packages\conda_build\api.py",
> line 253, in build
>         return build_tree(
>       File "C:\ProgramData\mambaforge-pypy3\lib\site-packages\conda_build\build.py",
> line 3804, in build_tree
>         packages_from_this = build(
>       File "C:\ProgramData\mambaforge-pypy3\lib\site-packages\conda_build\build.py",
> line 2474, in build
>         output_metas = expand_outputs([(m, need_source_download, need_reparse_in_env)])
>       File "C:\ProgramData\mambaforge-pypy3\lib\site-packages\conda_build\render.py",
> line 923, in expand_outputs
>         for output_dict, m in deepcopy(_m).get_output_metadata_set(
>       File "C:\ProgramData\mambaforge-pypy3\lib\site-packages\conda_build\metadata.py",
> line 2574, in get_output_metadata_set
>         conda_packages = finalize_outputs_pass(
>       File "C:\ProgramData\mambaforge-pypy3\lib\site-packages\conda_build\metadata.py",
> line 934, in finalize_outputs_pass
>         fm = finalize_metadata(
>       File "C:\ProgramData\mambaforge-pypy3\lib\site-packages\conda_build\render.py",
> line 637, in finalize_metadata
>         build_unsat, host_unsat = add_upstream_pins(
>       File "C:\ProgramData\mambaforge-pypy3\lib\site-packages\conda_build\render.py",
> line 452, in add_upstream_pins
>         build_deps, build_unsat, extra_run_specs_from_build = _read_upstream_pin_files(
>       File "C:\ProgramData\mambaforge-pypy3\lib\site-packages\conda_build\render.py",
> line 431, in _read_upstream_pin_files
>         deps, actions, unsat = get_env_dependencies(
>       File "C:\ProgramData\mambaforge-pypy3\lib\site-packages\conda_build\render.py",
> line 151, in get_env_dependencies
>         actions = environ.get_install_actions(
>       File "C:\ProgramData\mambaforge-pypy3\lib\site-packages\conda_build\environ.py",
> line 869, in get_install_actions
>         index, index_ts, _ = get_build_index(
>       File "C:\ProgramData\mambaforge-pypy3\lib\site-packages\conda_build\index.py",
> line 203, in get_build_index
>         _delegated_update_index(output_folder, verbose=debug)
>       File "C:\ProgramData\mambaforge-pypy3\lib\site-packages\conda_build\index.py",
> line 315, in _delegated_update_index
>         return _update_index(
>       File "C:\ProgramData\mambaforge-pypy3\lib\site-packages\conda_index\index\__init__.py",
> line 159, in update_index
>         channel_index.index(
>       File "C:\ProgramData\mambaforge-pypy3\lib\site-packages\conda_index\index\__init__.py",
> line 562, in index
>         futures = [
>       File "C:\ProgramData\mambaforge-pypy3\lib\site-packages\conda_index\index\__init__.py",
> line 562, in <listcomp>
>         futures = [
>       File "C:\ProgramData\mambaforge-pypy3\Lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py",
> line 609, in result_iterator
>         yield fs.pop().result()
>       File "C:\ProgramData\mambaforge-pypy3\Lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py",
> line 446, in result
>         return self.__get_result()
>       File "C:\ProgramData\mambaforge-pypy3\Lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py",
> line 391, in __get_result
>         raise self._exception
>       File "C:\ProgramData\mambaforge-pypy3\Lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py",
> line 58, in run
>         result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
>       File "C:\ProgramData\mambaforge-pypy3\lib\site-packages\conda_index\index\__init__.py",
> line 550, in extract_wrapper
>         return self.extract_subdir_to_cache(
>       File "C:\ProgramData\mambaforge-pypy3\lib\site-packages\conda_index\index\__init__.py",
> line 757, in extract_subdir_to_cache
>         cache.save_fs_state(subdir_path)
>       File "C:\ProgramData\mambaforge-pypy3\lib\site-packages\conda_index\index\sqlitecache.py",
> line 451, in save_fs_state
>         with self.db:
>       File "C:\ProgramData\mambaforge-pypy3\lib\site-packages\conda_index\index\sqlitecache.py",
> line 76, in __get__
>         value = self.wrapped(inst)
>       File "C:\ProgramData\mambaforge-pypy3\lib\site-packages\conda_index\index\sqlitecache.py",
> line 122, in db
>         convert_cache.migrate(conn)
>       File "C:\ProgramData\mambaforge-pypy3\lib\site-packages\conda_index\index\convert_cache.py",
> line 135, in migrate
>         remove_prefix(conn)
>       File "C:\ProgramData\mambaforge-pypy3\lib\site-packages\conda_index\index\convert_cache.py",
> line 160, in remove_prefix
>         conn.create_function("migrate_basename", narg=1, func=basename)
>       File "C:\ProgramData\mambaforge-pypy3\Lib\_sqlite3.py", line 324, in wrapper
>         return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
>       File "C:\ProgramData\mambaforge-pypy3\Lib\_sqlite3.py", line 305, in wrapper
>         return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
>     TypeError: create_function() got an unexpected keyword argument 'narg'
>
> `$ C:\ProgramData\mambaforge-pypy3\Scripts\conda-script.py build
> binda`
>
>   environment variables:
>                  CIO_TEST=<not set>
>     CONDA_ALLOW_SOFTLINKS=false
>         CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV=binda
>                 CONDA_EXE=C:\ProgramData\mambaforge-pypy3\condabin\..\Scripts\conda.exe
>                CONDA_EXES="C:\ProgramData\mambaforge-pypy3\condabin\..\Scripts\conda.exe"
>              CONDA_PREFIX=C:\Users\jlcas\anaconda3\envs\binda
>            CONDA_PREFIX_1=C:\ProgramData\mambaforge-pypy3
>     CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER=(binda)
>          CONDA_PYTHON_EXE=C:\ProgramData\mambaforge-pypy3\python.exe
>                CONDA_ROOT=C:\ProgramData\mambaforge-pypy3
>               CONDA_SHLVL=2
>            CURL_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
>                  HOMEPATH=\Users\jlcas
>                LD_PRELOAD=<not set>
>                      PATH=C:\Users\jlcas\anaconda3\envs\binda;C:\Users\jlcas\anaconda3\envs\bind
>                           a\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\Users\jlcas\anaconda3\envs\binda\Library\us
>                           r\bin;C:\Users\jlcas\anaconda3\envs\binda\Library\bin;C:\Users\jlcas\a
>                           naconda3\envs\binda\Scripts;C:\Users\jlcas\anaconda3\envs\binda\bin;C:
>                           \ProgramData\mambaforge-pypy3\condabin;C:\ProgramData\mambaforge-
>                           pypy3;C:\ProgramData\mambaforge-
>                           pypy3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\ProgramData\mambaforge-
>                           pypy3\Library\usr\bin;C:\ProgramData\mambaforge-
>                           pypy3\Library\bin;C:\ProgramData\mambaforge-pypy3\Scripts;C:\WINDOWS\s
>                           ystem32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Window
>                           sPowerShell\v1.0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program
>                           Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\010 Editor;C:\Program Files\dotnet;C:\U
>                           sers\jlcas\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;.;C:\sdk\flutter\bin;C:
>                           \Program Files\Android\Android
>                           Studio\jbr\bin;C:\Users\jlcas\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\bin\windows
>              PSMODULEPATH=C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\WINDOWS\system32\Windows
>                           PowerShell\v1.0\Modules
>                PYTHONPATH={PYTHONPATH};./src;./tests;../src;
>        REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
>             SSL_CERT_FILE=C:\Users\jlcas\anaconda3\envs\binda\Library\ssl\cacert.pem
>
>      active environment : C:\Users\jlcas\anaconda3\envs\binda
>     active env location : C:\Users\jlcas\anaconda3\envs\binda
>             shell level : 2
>        user config file : C:\Users\jlcas\.condarc  populated config files : C:\ProgramData\mambaforge-pypy3\.condarc
>                           C:\Users\jlcas\.condarc
>           conda version : 23.7.4
>     conda-build version : 3.26.1
>          python version : 3.9.17.final.0
>        virtual packages : __archspec=1=x86_64
>                           __cuda=11.2=0
>                           __win=0=0
>        base environment : C:\ProgramData\mambaforge-pypy3  (writable)
>       conda av data dir : C:\ProgramData\mambaforge-pypy3\etc\conda   conda av metadata url : None
>            channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
>                           https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
>                           https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
>                           https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
>                           https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
>                           https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
>                           https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
>                           https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
>           package cache : C:\ProgramData\mambaforge-pypy3\pkgs
>                           C:\Users\jlcas\.conda\pkgs
>                           C:\Users\jlcas\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
>        envs directories : C:\ProgramData\mambaforge-pypy3\envs
>                           C:\Users\jlcas\.conda\envs
>                           C:\Users\jlcas\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
>                platform : win-64
>              user-agent : conda/23.7.4 requests/2.31.0 PyPy/3.9.17 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.22621
>           administrator : False
>              netrc file : None
>            offline mode : False
>
>
> An unexpected error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report.
> If you suspect this error is being caused by a malfunctioning plugin,
> consider using the --no-plugins option to turn off plugins.
>
> Example: conda --no-plugins install <package>
>
> Alternatively, you can set the CONDA_NO_PLUGINS environment variable
> on the command line to run the command without plugins enabled.
>
> Example: CONDA_NO_PLUGINS=true conda install <package>
> ```

Comment: Seems to complain about the index. Does flushing the index cache help? I.e., try `conda clean -i`. Also, it is weird to be running `conda-build` in anything but **base**. That is the only environment where `conda`, `conda-build`, `mamba`, `boa`, etc. should be installed. So, maybe try deactivating out of the **binda** environment.

Comment: As a side note, if this is production-ready (as the 1.x implies) and on PyPI, I'd simply send it along to Conda Forge. No reason to be cluttering your repository with infrastructure to build a Conda version when Conda Forge will handle all that downstream from your PyPI releases.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed in the environment variables that this was using a different instance of conda from the one in the venv. I deleted the OS wide path entries for mambaforge and retried. This resolved the issue.